# Alloy - solution to Barber paradox still inconsistent

Tags: logic, alloy

It is known that the barber paradox is solved if there are multiple barbers so that they can shave each other.

This specification is consistent:

```
 sig Man {shaves: set Man} 
 some sig Barber extends Man {} 
 fact {   
   Barber.shaves = {m: Man | m not in m.shaves} 
 } 
 run { } for 4
```

However, the following, albeit it looks equivalent, is still inconsistent:

```
sig Man {
 shavedMen : set Man
}
fact {
 # {barber:Man | barber.shavedMen = {m: Man | m not in m.shavedMen} } > 1
}
run {} for 4
```

Why?

Answer (score 4):

In the first fact you constrain: 
that the set of man shaved by all barbers are all the men that do not shave themselves

**Edit**
my explanation of the second fact certainly lacked of clarity.
You state that a man is considered barber if the set of man he shaves is equal to the set of all men that do not shave themselves (him included, that's where the inconsistency comes from, and that's all the fun of this problem).

Comment: I see. So why is the second one inconsistent?

Comment: Thanks, Loic! In the second one I'm stating that the number of barbers is more than one (the outmost operator in the fact is >). This should have made the spec consistent (like in the first one), but it didn't. Any clue why?